# unable to append the select option using javascript which has dynamic php content

Tags: javascript, php

here is the form

```
<html>
<div id="prod">
<select name="type">
<?php while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($rset)) { 
echo "<option value= ".$row['type']."  > " .$row['type'] . "</option>" ;}?>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="add_product();" value="More Product" />
</div>
</html>
```

and the corresponding script, which reflect the only the text field but not the content from the table.

```
<script>
function add_product() {

var obj = document.getElementById('prod')
var append = document.createElement("div");
append.innerHTML = '<select name="type"> <?php while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($rset)) { echo "  <option value= ".$row['type']."  > " . $row['type'] . "</option>" ;}?> </select> ';

obj.appendChild(append)
}
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like, and what happens when you run this with a JavaScript console open?

Comment: So the PHP tags & code is actually being printed to the page?

Comment: The `<?php` is inside a quoted string, so is (probably) not being interpreted server-side.

Comment: I'm not sure it is to be honest? The php tags are inside the initial string mark after the variable assignment. So they wouldn't be string literals yet?

Comment: It appears, after a short test, that my guess was wrong.  (I had `<?php` inside single quotes, but without the database stuff.  It looks OK.)

Comment: So, what does the generated HTML look like?  That is, what does "view source" show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
   <div id="prod">
   <select name="type">
     <?php while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($rset)) { 
     echo "<option value= '".$row['type']."'  > " .$row['type'] . "</option>" ;}?>
   </select>
   <input type="button" onclick="add_product();" value="More Product" />
   </div>
</html>
```

> value= '".$row['type']."'